# Functional syntax for nested ifs

Tags: scala

sometimes I write code like the following:

```
val item1 = list.find(_.source.name.equals("foo"))
if (item1.isDefined) doSomething1(item1)
else {
  val item2 = list.find(_.dest.name.equals("bar"))
  if (item2.isDefined) doSomething2(item2)
  else doSomethingElse()
}
```

Does anyone have a nicer Scala syntax for laying this code out?

Comment: Are the doSomethings just for (side) effect, or do they return anything of significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd write this as

```
list.find(_.source.name =="foo").fold(doSomething1) {
  list.find(_.dest.name == "bar").fold(doSomething2)(doSomethingElse)
}
```

but that is because I have added the method `fold` to `Option` like so:

```
class FoldableOption[A](o: Option[A]) {
  def fold[Z](f: A => Z)(g: => Z) = o.map(f).getOrElse(g)
}
implicit def option_has_folds[A](o: Option[A]) = new FoldableOption(o)
```

If you don't want to add the `fold` method, you can also use the `map`, `getOrElse` pair:

```
list.find(_.source.name == "foo").map(doSomething1).getOrElse {
  list.find(_.dest.name == "bar").map(doSomething2).getOrElse(doSomethingElse)
}
```

which is not much more verbose.

Comment: The fold method for options also implemented in the [Scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/6.0.1-for-2.8.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/OptionW.scala#L16).

Answer (score 2):

Along with what Kevin said, it's better if these are expressions that return something.  I'm going to do the same thing as you but with a different concrete example:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
val result = list.find(_ == 1).map(
  _ => "Found1").orElse(list.find(_ == 5).map(
    _ => "Found2")).getOrElse("Found3")
```

However, yours may look better :)  But avoid side-effects.  Have the `if / else` chain, or monad chain be an expression that evaluates to something instead of some weird side-effecty kinda thing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though it'll be slightly slower:

```
val item1 = list find (_.source.name == "foo")
val item2 = list find (_.dest.name == "bar")
item1 map (doSomething1) orElse {
  item2 map (doSomething2)
} getOrElse doSomethingElse()
```

UPDATE: more efficiently, but not as neat:

```
val item1 = list find (_.source.name == "foo")
item1 map (doSomething1) orElse {
  val item2 = list find (_.dest.name == "bar")
  item2 map (doSomething2)
} getOrElse doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was avoiding (running find twice regardless).